Simple sorting question: Sorting average monthly rainfall data by chronological months over several decades
I'm trying simply to sort a set of monthly average rainfall data calculated from daily data over several decades. At present, the months are sorted alphabetically - i.e. April, August,..., September, following output from the calculation of the average using the aggregate function.
Of course, I require them sorted chronologically, then by year. I have spent several hours trawling through online help with functions and through explanations for similar, but subtly different problems on StackExchange, etc., but have struggled to find any solution that works.
I haven't used R for several years, so am rather rusty and no longer have colleagues to whom I can turn.
If someone can help, I'd be very grateful.
Thanks.
I calculate the monthly average as follows from the data frame rainfall.df, containing daily rainfall, the complete daily date, and separately, the month and year, abstracted from the date:
MonthlyAverageRF <- aggregate(rainfall.df$Rainfall ~ Month + Year, rainfall.df, mean)

Giving, in MonthlyAverageRF:
        Month Year rainfall.df$Rainfall
1       April 1961            2.2133333
2      August 1961            2.6225806
3    December 1961            2.0709677
4    February 1961            1.6571429
5     January 1961            2.4741935
6        July 1961            2.1645161
7        June 1961            0.8400000
8       March 1961            0.7225806
9         May 1961            0.6709677
10   November 1961            2.0966667
11    October 1961            3.0193548
12  September 1961            1.8100000

This is what I need, except, of course, the months are sorted alphabetically.
I tried sorting it by month chronologically using the following:
OrderedMonthlyRFAverage <- factor(MonthlyAverageRF, levels = MonthsInChronOrder)

where MonthsInChronOrder is a list of months in alphabetical order.
And, following another forum string
OrderedMonthlyRFAverage <- arrange(factor(MonthlyAverageRF$Month, levels = month.name))

Clearly I'm getting something simple wrong, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Hi Chris, you can help us help you if you provide the minimal code and data needed to demonstrate your problem, so we can copy paste and recreate.

Run rainfall.df$Month <- factor(rainfall.df$Month, levels = month.name) before running aggregate. This will coerce the months to factor with the correct levels order and that order will be used when you aggregate the data. (Note: month.nameis a R built-in constant, you don't need to create your own MonthsInChronOrder.)

That's perfect!! Sorted... So many thanks, Rui... I understand what's going on now...

BASE R solutions:
Change the data when aggregating:
aggregate(transform(rainfall.df, Month = factor(Month, month.name)), Rainfall~Year + Month, mean)
   Year     Month  Rainfall
1  1961   January 2.4741935
2  1961  February 1.6571429
3  1961     March 0.7225806
4  1961     April 2.2133333
5  1961       May 0.6709677
6  1961      June 0.8400000
7  1961      July 2.1645161
8  1961    August 2.6225806
9  1961 September 1.8100000
10 1961   October 3.0193548
11 1961  November 2.0966667
12 1961  December 2.0709677


aggregate(rainfall.df, Rainfall~Year + factor(Month, month.name), mean)

   Year factor(Month, month.name)  Rainfall
1  1961                   January 2.4741935
2  1961                  February 1.6571429
3  1961                     March 0.7225806
4  1961                     April 2.2133333
5  1961                       May 0.6709677
6  1961                      June 0.8400000
7  1961                      July 2.1645161
8  1961                    August 2.6225806
9  1961                 September 1.8100000
10 1961                   October 3.0193548
11 1961                  November 2.0966667
12 1961                  December 2.0709677


If you already have aggregated then use sort_by:
sort_by(MonthlyAverageRF, ~Year + factor(Month, month.name))
       Month Year  Rainfall
5    January 1961 2.4741935
4   February 1961 1.6571429
8      March 1961 0.7225806
1      April 1961 2.2133333
9        May 1961 0.6709677
7       June 1961 0.8400000
6       July 1961 2.1645161
2     August 1961 2.6225806
12 September 1961 1.8100000
11   October 1961 3.0193548
10  November 1961 2.0966667
3   December 1961 2.0709677


Many thanks for taking the time to answer my query...

Here is a tidyverse solution:
library(tidyverse)

# Create example dataset
rainfall.df <- data.frame(
  Month = c("April", "August", "December", "February", "January",
            "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", 
            "October", "September"),
  Year = rep(1961, 12),
  Rainfall = c(2.2133333, 2.6225806, 2.0709677, 1.6571429, 2.4741935, 
               2.1645161, 0.8400000, 0.7225806, 0.6709677, 2.0966667, 
               3.0193548, 1.8100000)
)

# Convert Month to a factor with specific order
rainfall.df %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = month.name)) %>%
  arrange(Year, Month)
#>        Month Year  Rainfall
#> 1    January 1961 2.4741935
#> 2   February 1961 1.6571429
#> 3      March 1961 0.7225806
#> 4      April 1961 2.2133333
#> 5        May 1961 0.6709677
#> 6       June 1961 0.8400000
#> 7       July 1961 2.1645161
#> 8     August 1961 2.6225806
#> 9  September 1961 1.8100000
#> 10   October 1961 3.0193548
#> 11  November 1961 2.0966667
#> 12  December 1961 2.0709677

Created on 2024-06-26 with reprex v2.1.0

Many thanks for the solution and your time to comment...
